# Symfony To publish an article has one hour handbook

Tags: php, symfony, date

Hello I have a blog with articles and I shall like posting an article one hour handbook for example has we are the 19/07/2018 I shall like posting the article July 25th has 3:30 pm

I have in my entity a property of type dateTime

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $isPublished;
```

My controller which allows me to show articles

```
/**
 * @Route("/", methods="GET|POST")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function index(Request $request): Response {

    $cookie = 'Bienvenue sur mon site web';
    setcookie('Al-houria.com', $cookie, time()+31536000, null, null, false, true);

    $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $dql   = "SELECT a FROM App:Articles a ORDER BY a.createdAt DESC";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $query, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
        10/*limit per page*/
    );


    return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
        'title' => 'Parce qu\'écrire est une liberté',
        'description' => 'Bienvenue sur Al-Houria.fr le blog culture et humeur d\'une passionnée du Moyen Orient.',
        'keywords' => 'Blog, Al-houria, Articles, Mondes, Actualité, Culture',
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ]);

}
```

In your opinion how I can make to show only articles with the date current and to show the other articles has their date respective

Thank you for your help cordially

Comment: "Hello I have a blog with articles and I shall like posting an article one hour handbook for example has we are the 19/07/2018 I shall like posting the article July 25th has 3:30 pm". Could you please rephrase? I do not understand what you mean. If you need to store the time as well as the date, your type should be `datetime` not `date`.

Comment: Hello thanks you for your answer ! I have an another question, did you know how I can do for programmate an article in a date or an hour that I choose ? Thanks you very much

Comment: Yes, you can do so with a query where you 'ask' the database for specific information. Please read about it.

Comment: what subject, can you have a link ?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the date is in the request. Here is how you call the date depending on which method you pass this date.

```
$request->query->get('date'); // GET
$request->request->get('date');  // POST
```

After you get the date, you can use it in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have to do how to make the comparison? I have to put it in the query dql?

Comment: i add this code :   ` $request->query->get('publishedAt');
        if($request >= new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'))) {
        $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $dql   = "SELECT a FROM App:Articles a ORDER BY a.createdAt DESC";
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
        }`

Comment: just put the date in the query dql

Comment: liek this : $dql   = "SELECT a FROM App:Articles a ORDER BY a.publishedAt DESC";

Comment: no, it will be like this `$dql = "SELECT a FROM App:Articles a WHERE a.publishedAt = " . $date`

Comment: I get an error of this type :  line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Literal, got end of string

Comment: I wrote this : $date = $request->request->get('publisehdAt');
        $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $dql   = "SELECT a FROM App:Articles a WHERE a.publishedAt = " . $date;
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html. check this link. it will help you.

Comment: I still do not find a solution It's not easy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176448/discussion-between-david-and-crown-backend).

Answer (score 1):

is works !!!!

```
/**
     * @Route("/", methods="GET")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request): Response {

        $cookie = 'Bienvenue sur mon site web';
        setcookie('Al-houria.com', $cookie, time()+31536000, null, null, false, true);

        $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        //SELECT * FROM articles WHERE published_at <= NOW() ORDER BY created_at DESC
        $dql = "SELECT a FROM App:Articles a WHERE a.publishedAt <= :date ORDER BY a.createdAt DESC";
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
        $query->setParameter('date', new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')));

        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $query, /* query NOT result */
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            10/*limit per page*/
        );


        return $this->render('index.html.twig', [
            'title' => 'Parce qu\'écrire est une liberté',
            'description' => 'Bienvenue sur Al-Houria.fr le blog culture et humeur d\'une passionnée du Moyen Orient.',
            'keywords' => 'Blog, Al-houria, Articles, Mondes, Actualité, Culture',
            'pagination' => $pagination
        ]);

    }
```